# Найти лучшего ученика по каждому предмету

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с оценками учеников:

### Grades

student_id - идентификатор ученика
subject_id - идентификатор предмета
grade      - оценка ученика по предмету

Написать запрос, который для каждого предмета возвращает идентификатор лучшего ученика.

[image: Данные таблицы]

Лучшее до чего додумался - как найти топ оценку для каждого предмета, но как пририсовать туда имена студентов недопёр.

(SELECT  `subject_id` , MAX( `grade`)
FROM grades
GROUP BY `subject_id`);

Финальный ответ должен выглядеть примерно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. описание функции RANK(). Ну и CTE, само собой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с функцией `RANK()`, она всем ученикам с наивысшей оценкой по предмету даст ранг 1:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT student_id, subject_id, grade, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id ORDER BY grade DESC) best
    FROM grades
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE best = 1;
```

---

PS Запрос не проверял, потому что в вопросе нет примера данных в текстовом виде.